# How to dynamically pass all of the jqgrid cell value when deleting a row

Tags: jqgrid, editing

I'm very new with JQGrid, so I apologize in advance if this a very 'duh' question..

The case is when I delete a row in the grid, jqgrid only pass the parameter id to the editurl. However, there are cases when I need more than one id parameter to delete a row, for instance for grid like this:

```
{UserID, Message} => {(user1, "hello"),(user1, "hola"),(user2,"hi")}
```

If i want to only delete the (user1, "hello") row, I need JQGrid to pass the parameter UserID=user1 and Message="hello" otherwise the (user1, "hello") and (user1, "hola") will be deleted.

I alreadt tried to modify the url before deleting by using onClickSubmit parameter:

```
onclickSubmit: function(rp_ge, postdata){
    rp_ge.url = 'RowManipulator.php?UserID='+$('#grid').getCell(postdata, 'UserID')+
                '&Message='+$('#grid').getCell(postdata,'Message');
```

However the resulted url (after checking on firebug) is:

```
RowManipulator.php?UserID=user1&Message=false
```

instead of `RowManipulator.php?UserID=user1&Message="hello"`. It seems that the message paramater can't be delivered.

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve what I intended to? Any help will be very appreciated

Updated:
Here is the jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid(
        { url:'DataFetcher.php',
          datatype: 'xml',
          mtype: 'GET',
          colNames:['UserId','Message'],
          colModel:[
              {name:'UserId',index:'UserId',width:75, editable:false,align: 'left'},
              {name:'Message',index:'Message',width:200, editable:true,align: 'left'}
          ],
          pager: jQuery('#pager'),
          rowNum:10,
          rowList:[10,20,30],
          sortname:'UserId',
          sortorder: "asc",
          viewrecords: true,
          imgpath: 'jqgrid/css/images',
          caption: 'MESSAGE',
          editurl:'RowManipulator.php',
          height: 350,
          width: 1000});
     jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{},
         {height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:true},
         {height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:true},
         {onclickSubmit: function(rp_ge, postdata){
             rp_ge.url = 'RowManipulator.php?UserId='
                         $('#list').getCell(postdata, 'UserId') &&
                         Message=$('#list').getCell(postdata,Message);
         },
         reloadAfterSubmit:true},
         {sopt:['cn','eq']})
```

Comment: Could you post the JavaScript code with the jqGrid? Which version of jqGrid you use?

Comment: Hi Oleg, 

I use Jqgrid 3.7.1 and the I've posted the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
rp_ge.url = 'RowManipulator.php?UserId='
                         $('#list').getCell(postdata, 'UserId') &&
                         Message=$('#list').getCell(postdata,Message);
```

has syntax errors. Is `postdata` not already contain the 'UserId'? Then `$('#list').getCell(postdata, 'UserId')` will gives you back `postdata`.

Try with

```
rp_ge.url = 'RowManipulator.php?UserId=' +
             $('#list').getCell(postdata, 'UserId') +
             'Message=' + $('#list').getCell(postdata,'Message');
```

or better with

```
rp_ge.url = 'RowManipulator.php?' +
            jQuery.param({UserId: $('#list').getCell(postdata, 'UserId'),
                          Message: $('#list').getCell(postdata, 'Message')});
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, I've tried your answer and I still get the same problem, the UserId parameter is passed successfully but the Message parameter is passed as "false".. any idea?

Comment: Sorry Dorian, but something is wrong what you write me. I created some test page http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataFetcher.htm with your data. If you try delete a row you will see alerts with correct data. I have no 'RowManipulator.php' on my site, but I can see in Fiddler, that jqGrid post data like "oper=del&id=2" to the url `http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/RowManipulator.php?UserId=user1&Message=hola`. So all work like I described. You can see source of my test data under http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataFetcher.xml

Comment: Hi Oleh,

Many Thanks for the answer, I've checked again and everything works well, it turns out that JqGrid is case-sensitive in terms of the the column naming, that is the reason why I got "false" as the value.